# PHP как обьединить повторяющиеся переменные в методах класса

Tags: php, ооп, классы, методы

```
    class SiteController{



public function actionIndex() {
      $menu = Menu::getMenuList();
      $slider = Slider::getSliderList();
      $slider_mini = Slider::getSliderMiniList();
      $news = News::getNewsList();
    }

        public function actionSale(){
          $menu = Menu::getMenuList();
          $slider = Slider::getSliderList();
          $slider_mini = Slider::getSliderMiniList();
          $sale = Sale::getSaleList();
        }

        public function actionArticles(){
          $menu = Menu::getMenuList();
          $slider = Slider::getSliderList();
          $slider_mini = Slider::getSliderMiniList();
          $articles = Articles::getArticlesList();
        }

    }
```

Вопрос как объединить

```
$menu = Menu::getMenuList();
  $slider = Slider::getSliderList();
  $slider_mini = Slider::getSliderMiniList();
```

что бы не повторялся код?

Comment: Каким образом вы используете эти переменные в классе `SiteController`?

Comment: Зачем результат вызова статических методов записывается в локальные переменные, которые нигде не используются? Уточните, пожалуйста, что делают методы get...List().

Comment: getSliderList() возвращает массив для слайдера, который потом выводится на страницу. `public function actionArticles(){
 $menu = Menu::getMenuList();
 $slider = Slider::getSliderList();
 $slider_mini = Slider::getSliderMiniList();
 $articles = Articles::getArticlesList();
    
   // Подключаем вид
 require_once(ROOT . '/views/site/index.php');
 return true;
    
}` в конце подключается вид и все выводится на страницу

Comment: я бы покопал в сторону middleware и декораторов. они тут на лицо. тем более что речь про контроллер.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вариант с массивом и `list`ом:

```
private function initMenuAndSlider() {
    return [Menu::getMenuList(),
        Slider::getSliderList(),
        Slider::getSliderMiniList()];
}

public function actionArticles() {
    list($menu,$slider,$slider_mini) = $this->initMenuAndSlider();
    $articles = Articles::getArticlesList();
}
```

> [list](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php) — Присваивает переменным из списка значения подобно массиву

list - позволяет имитировать возврат нескольких параменных через массив (как в питоне)

Вариант с ассоциативным массивом и `extract`ом:

```
private function initMenuAndSlider() {
    $arr = [];
    $arr['menu'] = Menu::getMenuList();
    $arr['slider'] = Menu::getSliderList();
    $arr['slider_mini'] = Menu::getSliderMiniList();
    return $arr;
}

public function actionArticles() {
    extract($this->initMenuAndSlider());
    $articles = Articles::getArticlesList();
}
```

> [extract](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php) — Импортирует переменные из массива в текущую таблицу символов

Comment: ужас какой.....

Comment: Недостаток этого варианта - initMenuAndSlider() возвращает индексированный массив, содержимое которого не очевидно. Поэтому 1. каждый раз при его вызове надо читать его код, чтобы убедиться, что переменные присваиваются в правильном порядке 2. если нужно возвратить в методе еще один элемент, придется дописывать переменные к каждому вызову метода. Скорее всего, автор вопроса не нуждается в локальных переменных, но, тем не менее, ответ пока подходит и работает.

Comment: В смысле "пока" работает? Работает - так плюсуйте :)

Comment: Работает, работает!) Спасибо плюснул+ , спасибо а главное понял как работает, я искал но наткнулся на compact() а там немного не так. А про эту функцию не знал.

Comment: Я когда думал как решить эту проблему тоже думал про массив, хотел что то свое придумывать, а оказывается есть готовое. А есть еще какой то вариант ну например через Базовый класс или __construct  что бы автоподгружалось. Пробовал но не получилось Базовый  __construct не учавствует в самом методе дочернего класса, или нет?

Comment: Его надо самому вызывать в дочернем конструкторе `parent::__construct();`

Comment: отличный пример, как сделать проблему из ничего

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - сделать инициализирующий метод `initMenuAndSlider`, куда вынести эти три повторяющихся метода и в экшенах вызывать уже его.

Однако логика тут в принципе неверная. Потому что контроллер сайта не должен знать что-то о меню или слайдерах. Обычно такие вещи лежат в виджетах. Также новости и статьи должны загружаться совсем другим контроллером, например `PublishingController`.

Поэтому в данном случае предлагать какие-то костыли в принципе не имеет смысла, потому что это неразумно.

Comment: Есть роутер который из массива загружает соответственный Контролер,`'/^index.php$/' => 'site/index', // actionIndex в SiteController)` и как к этой странице index подключить разные контролеры? У меня Экшены получают данные от моделей. Ну да не совершенная логика, но она работает.

Comment: @Nikolay меня сбивают фразы `Есть роутер который из массива загружает соответственный Контролер` и `как к этой странице index подключить разные контролеры?`. Это две друг другу противоположные фразы. Либо у вас роутер разруливает и тогда не вижу проблем. Либо не разруливает, и значит надо писать правильный маршрутизатор, который как раз, как вы и написали, в зависимости от `url` и будет принимать решение какой контроллер и экшн в текущий момент брать.

Comment: Мы друг друга наверное не поняли, Про роутер  - это то как у меня есть, а про Индекс это вопрос к Вам. У меня есть  `SiteController` методы которого отвечают за отображение каждый своей страницы (главная, акции, контакты, товары, и т.д.)  Вот а теперь вопрос? - зачем мне `PublishingController` если статьи загружаются методом `actionArticles`. Вы наверное предлагаете для каждой страницы создавать свой Контролер? наверное так тоже можно, но вопрос был (как обьединить повторяющиеся переменные в методах класса

)  что бы избавиться от избыточного и повторяющегося кода. Спасибо за участие ;-)

Comment: @Nikolay `зачем мне PublishingController если статьи загружаются методом actionArticles` - я это писал в ответе: неправильно заставлять один контроллер, один класс делать ВСЮ работу сайта. Должно быть разграничение. Например, за отображение списка новостей/статей должен отвечать News/Articles контроллер, а не Site. Получается есть фен, он по нажатию одной кнопки - сушит волосы, другой - готовит кофе, третьей - показывает телевизионные новости, четвертой - вообще в космос отправляет. Это неправильно. А как объединить повторяющиеся участки кода - логично что объединив их в один метод/функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы не вынисите переменные
    $menu 
    $slider
    $slider_mini
в сам класс 
тогда не понадобится эта ерунда
    $slider = Slider::getSliderList();
    $slider_mini = Slider::getSliderMiniList();
и не будет куча ненужных и захламляющих память переменных

Comment: Мысль здравая, но сумбурная. Несколько раз перечитывал, чтобы понять

Comment: Не могу понять чем упростит вынос этих переменных в сам класс? Страницу оформляет Метод класса, сам класс используется больше для маршрутизации. И если в Методе который  отображает страницу нет этих переменных, то их нет соответственно и на странице. Я пробовал через базовый класс но что то не получилось с__construct сам констракт есть но переменные не появляются на странице. Ребята не судите строго лучше дайте понятный код для этой ситуации.

Comment: @Nikolay тем что можно будет их все инициировать в конструкторе.

Comment: я пробовал эти переменные выводить в конструкторе, но на странице ничего не вывелось, может я где то ошибся? Если не трудно положите здесь Код, я посмотрю может я что то не понял. На живом примере проще понять о чем идет речь. Спасибо за участие)